# How can I never see scroll bars?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I can change the scroll bar behaviour to only show when scrolling:

 > System Preferences... > General > Show scroll bars

[image: When scrolling]

But I never want to see scroll bars.

How can I completely disable them? I just want to scroll with keyboard/trackpad, the scroll bars are ugly and get in the way too often, and I never have a need for them.

I want to turn off scroll bars 100%.

Answer (score 2):

You get the three options shown. That's it. macOS makes no provision for your particular desire in its design.

You should make an enhancement request at [Apple's Product Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) site.

Comment: What have _you_ done to search for third-party tools? You don't indicate any effort, on your part, to find the answer for yourself. Part of the philosophy at AskDifferent is to ask questions when you have tried, but failed, to find the answer for yourself. IMHO, scroll-bars are an integral part of any modern operating system, and your desire to disable them is perhaps difficult or impossible to effect in software.

Comment: Good luck. I don't there is such a setting.